Nginx OpenResty : How to Use Lua in NGINX Stream Context for Modifying TCP/UDP Traffic Response
I'm trying to use Lua scripting with NGINX to handle TCP/UDP traffic within the stream context. Specifically, I want to modify the response data being proxied through my NGINX server using Lua. I've seen examples using the http context with directives like header_filter_by_lua and body_filter_by_lua based on : https://gist.github.com/ejlp12/b3949bb40e748ae8367e17c193fa9602
this work great for http directive.
header_filter_by_lua and body_filter_by_lua  not exist for stream directive like this :
stream {

    server {
        listen 12345;
        proxy_pass 10.0.0.1:567;
    }
}

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
  stream {
    
        server {
            listen 12345;

 preread_by_lua_block {
            local sock = ngx.req.socket()
            local data, err = sock:receive("*a")
            if not data then
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to read data: ", err)
                return
            end

            -- Modify data
            local modified_data = string.gsub(data, "old_text", "new_text")
            ngx.req.set_body_data(modified_data)
        }


            proxy_pass 10.0.0.1:567;
        }
    }

but is not working

Varnish cache is probably the best tool for this, but I think you need Varnish Enterprise. Maybe this will help https://samanbaboli.medium.com/modify-html-pages-on-the-fly-using-nginx-2e7a2d069086

I am investigating kind of same problem and it seems like openresty is not giving your any tools to achieve that. At your example it's impossible to do  ngx.req.set_body_data(modified_data) cause it's is part of http context API, while you are trying to deal with stream. In other words you are trying to manipulate L4(tcp traffic) with L7(http) methods which is not make sense.
There are only one possible workaround - using cosoket API during access phase  (use access_by_lua directive) and implement direct socket to socket communication with your upstream server, but this is really tricky.
So in conclusion - I don't think it's possible with tools openresty provided. But you can try to use another server like apache or squid, I can't recommend you neither. If you find any way to manipulate tcp traffic with openresty without implementing s2s communication comment me, I will be glad to know.

I wonder if it's possible with Varnish or HAProxy

Guess I found smth interesting, try maproxy https://github.com/zferentz/maproxy/tree/master according to this sample https://github.com/zferentz/maproxy/blob/master/demos/logging_proxy.py you can take a control over upstream data with on_p2s_done_read and then put modified data to the super.on_p2s_done_read. Unless it seems to be kind of outdated it satisfy declared needs. Have a look and let me know if it's handy for you. @nikolay @AHmedRef
